# How do I see total "Sessions" for certain pages on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

On Google Analytics, I can use the Behavior tab to see the details of my pages and how many Page Views and Unique Page Views they generated.

I want to know if there is a way to select a number of pages and see how many unique Sessions those pages had.

For example, if I myself visited a few pages from my site, this is how Analytics currently shows it:

```
Page            Page Views    Unique Page Views
-----------------------------------------------
/index.html     5             1
/about.html     2             1
/contact.html   1             1
-----------------------------------------------
                8             3
```

There's no way to know all of this was generated by 1 session. How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single page, Google Analytics is already giving you the number you want: "unique page views".

- **Pageviews** -- The number of times the page has been viewed (including multiple times by the same user).
- **Unique page views** -- The number of sessions that have included a view of the page.

Source: http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/google-analytics-views-vs-unique-views-3472.html

---

To know how many sessions that touched any of a set of pages, you can create advanced segment for traffic that viewed any of those pages:

[image: create google analytics segment]

Then you can view a report such as "Audience Overview" with this segment applied.  That will tell you how many sessions touch any of these pages.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the second method suggested by Stephen for a set of pages will show incorrect data. As detailed by [Analytics Edge](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-sessions-for-pages/), "Google tags the Session count only to the first page viewed".
This means that the above example segment will only show sessions where "/section/" is the first page in a session and will not count the sessions where this page comes is in second place or later.

Answer (score 0):

David is correct. Basically GA records the Session hit only for the Landing Page (first page) of a session and not subsequent pages.

Hence if you are looking for the number of sessions in which a particular page was viewed, one should look at the Unique Page View column.

One can view this by following the below path
Behaviour -> Site Content -> All Pages and looking at the Unique Page View column.